Why is ${(e^{(i×1)})}^π$ different from $e^{(i×π)}$
I found in calculator that
\begin{align*}
e^{i \times 1} &= \cos 1 + i \sin 1  \\
    &= 0.540302306 + 0.841470985 i
\end{align*}
and I know that $e^{i\times\pi} = -1$.
My doubt is that
\begin{align*}
(e^{1\times i})^π &= (0.540302306 + 0.841470985 i)^π  \\
    &= -1 + 2.25021227 × 10^{-11} i
\end{align*}
but not exactly equals to $-1$ but according to exponents $(e^{i\times1})^π$ must be equal to $e^{i\times\pi}$
But numerically there is difference between them why?

Note that the value your calculator gave for $e^{i \pi}$ is $-1 + i \epsilon$ for $\epsilon$ small. Your calculator is presumably calculating things here numerically which causes this imprecision.

The software you used to compute this, made a rounding error.
For example cos(1) is not equal to 0.540302306, it is approximately equal to this value.

You think that's weird, what about this: why is $3\times\frac13=3\times0.333333333333333=0.999999999999999$ when it should be $1$?

First,
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}} &= 0.54\,030\,230\,586\,813\,971\,740\,093{\dots}  \\
&\qquad + 0.84\,147\,098\,480\,789\,650\,665\,250{\dots}\mathrm{i}
\end{align*}
The ellipses represent infinitely many digits that we elide (that is, that we do not write down).  As you can see, your calculator did the best job it could presenting the answer with fewer digits, but the answer given is not exactly the value of $\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}}$.  It rounded the true value, so the value of the quantity was distorted by a tiny amount.  So what the calculator actually told you is:

The real part of $\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}}$ is in the interval $[0.5403023055, 0.5403023065)$.
The imaginary part of $\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}}$ is in the interval $[0.8414709845, 0.8414709855)$.

Both of these are true; your calculator has calculated properly.
That means that your calculator showed you a result with nine digits of accuracy.  You should not expect the subsequent step (raising to the power $\pi$) will have much better precision that than.  It did, having ten digits of accuracy, probably because the binary value the calculator had in memory was a little more precise than the rounded decimal value you could see.  (I say ten digits because the error is 2 in the eleventh decimal place of the imaginary part, so the first ten decimal digits -- all zeroes -- are correct.)

As an example of the difficulties posed by exponentiating by $\pi$, there's the fact that we numerically checking that pi^pi^pi^pi is not an integer is beyond our computational reach (as covered by Stand-Up Maths here).
